# Add break line each X characters

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to automaticaly break line a div content each, let's say, 50 characters. For that I have this script but it doesn't seems to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/3sj2644z/4/

```
function breakline(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var length = $this.html().length;
    if(length % 50 == 0) {
        $this.val($this.html() + "\n");
}
```

Any advice ?

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: @DavidThomas When you write in the textarea, the text is displayed in the div. But when the div content length is 50,100,150,200 or 250, it should add the "\n" to break the line, so the displayed text will not be on only one line.

Comment: That's what it should do, but in what way is it not working? I'm trying to lead you towards an [edit] of your question to ask a full, self-contained question. Please, take a read of the "*[ask]*" guidelines.

Comment: Btw, you forgot to close your if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `long_string.replace(/(.{50})/g, "$1<br>");`

```js
var long_string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vel vestibulum orci. Vestibulum pulvinar sapien nec massa molestie volutpat. Duis iaculis arcu placerat odio tempor, vel venenatis nisi congue. Sed fermentum felis sed nulla mollis, at rhoncus velit condimentum. Phasellus luctus lorem justo, cursus tempus tortor laoreet quis. Pellentesque odio nibh, interdum vel ultrices sit amet, vestibulum vitae libero. Aenean vel porta quam. Morbi tincidunt diam vulputate, varius mi vel, interdum justo. Maecenas justo neque, mollis in ante ac, suscipit rhoncus sem.Vivamus vestibulum sapien mauris, quis mollis nunc auctor a. Phasellus rutrum turpis et rutrum semper. Aliquam tincidunt, orci quis convallis rutrum, lectus sapien vulputate dolor, in fermentum sem nisi et nisl. In consectetur purus risus, vitae tempor ante fermentum a. Integer ut accumsan nibh. Donec sagittis justo quam, sollicitudin vehicula leo dapibus vel. Maecenas a augue non mauris blandit accumsan. Vivamus semper fermentum nulla, quis laoreet velit egestas sit amet. Mauris ut euismod risus. Donec sit amet cursus sapien. Cras molestie arcu aliquet ipsum posuere volutpat vel id erat.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean justo libero, sagittis ut facilisis vel, hendrerit non dolor. Fusce egestas elit nec mauris aliquet elementum sodales in lacus. Aenean posuere, mauris quis pellentesque tristique, tellus eros vestibulum leo, in pretium arcu tellus vitae enim. Sed feugiat, ante eu molestie sodales, nunc tortor accumsan ligula, eget feugiat elit velit sed risus. Nulla feugiat libero imperdiet dictum commodo. Vivamus sit amet neque libero. Curabitur interdum nibh at purus pretium, id ornare magna aliquet. Vivamus accumsan varius laoreet. Suspendisse non ante in felis laoreet interdum sit amet eget velit. Proin cursus vulputate semper. Donec id nunc tortor. Vestibulum vulputate turpis eu dui mollis, in pretium lorem tempus.";

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = long_string.replace(/(.{50})/g, "$1<br>");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: @SachithMW Added one for you.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Thank u very much :)

Comment: @Ezhno ok dude,can you explain properly what u need ??? isn't this solution what u expect ???

Comment: @SachithMW I figured out by myself :) Thanks

Comment: @Ezhno ok dude :)

Comment: @SachithMW How could I add a condition to avoid words breaking ? Like if the 50th character isn't a space, then it doesn't break line until there a new space (so that the word is complete and not cuted on two lines)

Answer (score 1):

What You are doing there is adding a break line only in case when the whole text has 50 characters. 

What You should do is:

 - split string every 50 characters if it is longer than 50 characters

 - and join them with '\n' 

The below code will split your string into lines of 50 characters:

```
lines = str.match(/.{50}/g);
```

Now, You can join them with:

```
lines.join('<br>');
```

Or You can use a one liner:

```
str.replace(/(.{50})/g, "$1<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created an answer similar to your approach. Since the value of `textg` is getting the value of the `textarea` when `length % 50` equals `0` I had a line break to the `textarea`. I also added `white-space` `pre-line` which

> will break lines where they break in code, but extra white space is still stripped.

[Learn more about whitespace here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/).

I have stripped all javascript from your html and put it all in one function `breakline()`.

```js
function breakline(e) {
    var $this = $(this);   // store text area element
    var $textg = $('#textg');   // store div element
    var length = $this[0].value.length;  // get length of text within textarea
    $textg[0].textContent = $this[0].value; // set text content of div to text of textarea
    if(length % 50 === 0) {                 // test if text in textarea is divisble by 50 with a remainder of 0 
      $this[0].value += '\n';         // add line break to textarea
    }
}

$('#text-g').on('input', breakline); // changed from keyup to input since keyup will call breakline only when a key is released
```

```css
#textg {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <textarea id="text-g" name="text-g" maxlength="300" placeholder="Message de copropriétée"></textarea>
</form>

<div id='textg' class='textg'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to tackle this myself by manually creating an array, but I have to concede the other answers using:

- `match()` and `join()`; and
- `regex` and `replace()`

are less verbose and more elegant.

```js
var chars = 50;
var withBreaks = document.getElementsByClassName('with-breaks')[0];
var withBreaksText = withBreaks.textContent;
var withBreaksTextLength = withBreaksText.length;
var withBreaksArray = [];
var j = 0;

for (var i = chars; i < (withBreaksText.length + chars); i = i + chars) {
withBreaksArray[j] = withBreaksText.substring(0,(chars + 1));
withBreaksText = withBreaksText.substring(chars + 1);
j++;
}

withBreaks.textContent = '';

for (var i = 0; i < withBreaksArray.length; i++) {
withBreaks.innerHTML += withBreaksArray[i] + '<br />';
}
```

```html
<p class="with-breaks">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut alia vidit splendide qui, sit modo consetetur no. Duo eu affert vocibus argumentum. Ut mei delenit molestiae. Eum agam albucius appetere ad, eum ex debitis omnesque singulis, eu vidit concludaturque ius. Ea mei dicat partiendo, mazim aliquando sea eu, quot clita salutatus no vim. Cibo complectitur ea sed, ad prima veritus nec. Facer verear periculis eu quo, in per molestie honestatis. Quem quas persecuti cu nec. Ei tation corpora his. Amet iriure ex has, aliquam sanctus vim eu. Deserunt gubergren has cu. Dico nominavi dissentias ea his, vel te stet verear repudiare, duo quis scripta aliquam ut. Qui menandri platonem ne, eu eum abhorreant scribentur, usu etiam euismod lobortis et. His vivendo propriae ad. An nam congue suscipit consectetuer, mea te eleifend tractatos signiferumque. Nominavi sapientem salutatus no nec. Ad nisl sint ipsum his. Lorem aperiam repudiare no nec. Melius discere mea ei. Quas modus contentiones ex vim. Hinc lorem torquatos eu vim, brute intellegam ne nec, quo ne aeterno fuisset principes. Sea et eripuit gubergren, eu impetus aliquid definitiones nec, te alii wisi nam. Est indoctum qualisque eu, tantas splendide reprehendunt an pri. Sea perpetua dissentiunt definitionem at. Stet harum sit ad.</p>
```